# PHP Excel Date field value while importing in php mysql its giving some integer value

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem when importing an Excel file into a MySQL database using PHP. It's showing an integer value for every date field value.

For example, suppose there is a date 16-06-2012 in my Excel date field. It's showing 41076 when imported with PHP.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

MS Excel Default takes 01-01-1900 basedate
You can easily convert excel integer date value into Date type in php
See

```
$intdatevalue=excel date value in integer

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('1899-12-31+'.($intdatevalue-1).' days'));
```

1899-12-31 because year 1900 count as a leap year.

It will solve your excel date import problems

Answer (score 2):

```
function ExcelToPHP($dateValue = 0, $ExcelBaseDate=0) {
    if ($ExcelBaseDate == 0) {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 25569;
        //  Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
        if ($dateValue < 60) {
            --$myExcelBaseDate;
        }
    } else {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 24107;
    }

    // Perform conversion
    if ($dateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $dateValue - $myExcelBaseDate;
        $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    // Return
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Pass in:

```
your Excel date (e.g. 41076)
(optionally) a flag 0 or 4 to reflect the Excel base calendar.
    This is most likely to be 0
```

Output is the PHP timestamp value

```
$excelDate = 41076;
$timestamp = ExcelToPHP($excelDate);
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);

echo $mysqlDate, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: When i try to convert 69704 into MySQL date it returns date as '1954-09-26' instead of '2090-11-02'.

Comment: @Saurabh - Then you're probably running on a 32-bit version of PHP, which has a date range of between 1901-12-13 and 2038-01-19.... if you need to use dates outside of this range, then switch to using a 64-bit version of PHP

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me how to check if the PHP version is 32 bit or 64 bit ?

Comment: `echo PHP_INT_SIZE;`.... a response of `4` is 32-bit, a response of `8` is 64-bit

Comment: Thanks. I am indeed on 32-bit PHP. I need to check XAMPP to find the one which support 64-bit. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$intdatevalue=excel date value in integer

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('1899-12-31+'.($intdatevalue-1).' days'));
```

This answer is the best. I even did not know that Excel takes dates from 01-01-1900. So I owe this man a lot.

I always like timestamp dates.

Answer (score -2):

Dates in Excel are stored using a number of days since Unix epoch.

You can probably do something like this:

```
$excelDate = 41076;
$timestamp = $excelDate * 60 * 60 * 24;
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Incorrect - base date for Excel is either 31-Dec-1899 or 1st Jan 1904 (depending on Windows or Mac calendar settings) - this is not Unix epoch